# How to remove CLIENT TRANSFER PROHIBITED status from my domain name

Tags: domains

I need help on how to get register.com to remove the CLIENT TRANSFER PROHIBITED status from my domain name so I can transfer it. Please what do I need to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You likely have `lock` set on the domain which is meant to prevent unauthorized transfers to another registrar. Log into your current registrar's domain control panel/manager and look for the option to `unlock` it.

Other possibilities are that your domain is past the expiration date, in which it would go into a redemption stage for a period of time and not be eligible for transfer (check the `expiration` date in a WHOIS lookup for your domain). Or, you registered the domain or changed the registrant information within the past 60 days, which by ICANN rules would prevent the transfer for that period of time.

For a complete list of reasons why a registrar may deny a transfer see section `3. Obligations of the Registrar of Record` in:

[ICANN - Policy on Transfer of Registrations between Registrars](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/registrars/transfers/policy)

Comment: Thanks Dan. My web site was built by web.com and they did not tell me that register.com was going to be the owner of my domain name which I paid for and own the service mark for my business. From your experience do you think I might have difficulty transferring domain name?

Comment: No problem. Who is listed as the registrant in a WHOIS lookup for your domain? If it's another party, then you'll have to get their agreement to do the transfer. If you own the trademark in the country in which it was registered, then you can file a UDRP in the case where you're not able to gain their cooperation.

Comment: BTW, this is one of the major issues with using a web design/development service that charges little or nothing upfront - you may have to keep paying them to keep the website up or under your control. In your case, having the trademark is very helpful, though a UDRP is not an easy process go to through. I would contract them and do your best to negotiate releasing the domain prior to going through the UDRP process.