# How can I recover a domain in clientTransferProhibited state?

Tags: domain-registration

A member of a society had registered a `.org` domain for the society, which the provider somehow now refuses to give out (some mixup about invoices involved).

The current domain status is:

```
Creation Date: 2010-01-27T14:02:09Z
Updated Date: 2013-10-21T00:20:28Z
Registry Expiry Date: 2015-01-27T14:02:09Z
Sponsoring Registrar:united-domains AG (R1838-LROR)
Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 1408
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited
```

How can I recover the domain for the society? I am fully capable of legally representing the society on my own. I do not, however, have any experience with handling domains, other than asking my own provider to “accept” them and telling them some auth code. (Running nameservers, etc. is something I know how to do, again.) I wish for this domain to be transferred to a provider where the society has control about.

A bit more explanation: the member of the society is listed as both Admin and Registrant, but cannot do anything because the registrar (United Domains) is acting up.

This is, apparently, a time-sensitive issue.

Comment: What kind of domain is it? Different domain registries have different policies on these things.

Comment: "Log into your current registrar's domain control panel/manager and look for the option to unlock it." - Quoted from [How to remove CLIENT TRANSFER PROHIBITED status from my domain name](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53072/47483)

Comment: @NikhilSupekar the member CANNOT do anything currently, because the registrar is acting up. However, he is both Admin and Registrant.

Comment: Here is an answer that may give you some ideas: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61346/getting-access-to-website-files-without-access-to-the-hosting-account/61347#61347 Ignore the title. It is a somewhat similar situation. These things can be done. But you do have to have your ducks in a row and ready to present your case fully and absolutely.

Comment: Hm. In the end, the fix was social: the member refused to contact UI about payment/solution, but our non-technical member of the managing board phoned them, said he had proof the domain belongs to the society, and they handed it over. Apparently, sufficient social skills were enough here (which I freely admit I do not have). So, I suggest closing this.

Answer (score 1):

For a .org, your options are limited. I'm not aware of any way to transfer a locked domain to a new registrar without the cooperation of the existing registrar. I can only suggest that you contact United Domains, explain the situation, mend any bridges that have been burned and pay any invoices that they think are outstanding.

Comment: Is there anything “the society” (as legal entity) can do? The domain is currently the name of the society, minus `e.V.` (legal suffix for such things in Germany) plus `.org`, and had been registered by a private individual, for us, back when we were not yet “incorporated” (if that’s the correct English word). Can we request the domain to be handed over to us, since the private individual “obviously” has nothing to do with it?